# Rebol - How can I append text from a text field to a text list?

Tags: rebol, red, rebol3, rebol2

I've been exploring the amazing Rebol programming tool. I've run into a problem of trying to append text from a text field into the data of a text-list. My code below adds text to the text-list but changes all previous text to the current one multiplied by how many data entries were already in the text list.

How can I correct this?

```
REBOL [
    Title: "test4"
    Version: 1.3.3
    Author: "me"
    Purpose: {create a list of countries}
]

populate: does[
    country: countryField/text
    append txtList/data country
    show lay
]

lay: layout [
    across
    text "Enter name of country" black bold
    countryField: field
    return
    across
    txtList: text-list 
    panel [
        button "Add" [populate]
        button "Delete" [remove back tail txtList/data show lay]
        button "Clear" [clear txtList/data show lay]
    ]
]

view lay
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `copy` the text:

```
country: copy countryField/text
```

For short, without copying a series (a string in this case) you just append the same one multiple times, it is all the same string. When you change it you just change one string but you see it as multiple changes.

Here you can read the detailed explanation:

https://github.com/red/red/wiki/%5BDOC%5D-Why-you-have-to-copy-series-values

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain. Just made the corrections and it works. Do you use Rebol to make stuff? Thanks

Comment: Yes I'm using Rebol2 and Red both for daily use, mostly to filter, organize, search, convert data (lazy to open Excel), a CLI console, I use them on production as well. Community is small but welcoming:
http://rebol.info/
https://gitter.im/red/home